# arrow pointing at braket

Tags: braket

I am trying to put an arrow under the first part of a braket. The equation I use is the `\braket{a}{b}`. I have managed to put an arrow under the braket using a `\coeff{}{}` code suggested on a previous topic but I want the arrow to point at the first part of the braket and not the middle of the braket. Also under the arrow I need to have another letter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's very hard to help you without seeing some actual code. Please make a minimal compilable document (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows the problem and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I would suggest also a basic picture of what you would to obtain. You could draw by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might want to do something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$%\tikznodestyle 
  #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\[\braket{\tikznode{a}{a}|\tikznode{b}{b}}\qquad 
\Braket{\tikznode{cat0}{\SchrodingersCat{0}}|\tikznode{cat1}{\SchrodingersCat{1}}}\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[-latex,thin] ([yshift=-8pt]a.south) -- (a);
\draw[-latex,thin] ([yshift=8pt]cat0.north) -- (cat0);
\draw[-latex,thin] ([yshift=-2pt]cat1.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]cat1.south east);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP said "braket", not "bra-cat"! LOL!

Comment: The `|` does give nice cleavage, though...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, that's the difference between `\braket` and `\Braket`. Meow! ;-)